# Value of this inside a Proxy trap

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-proxy

I have the following code:

```js
function delay(f, ms) {
    return new Proxy(f, {
        apply(target, thisArg, args) {
            console.log(this)
            console.log(thisArg)
            setTimeout(() => f.apply(thisArg, args), ms)
        }
    })
}

function sayHi(user) {
    alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}

sayHi = delay(sayHi, 3000);


let container = {
    f: sayHi
}

container.f("Paul")
```

Why is `this` inside the `apply` function equal to `{apply: f}` and not to the container object? `this` is the object before dot, isn't it?

Comment: Because `apply` is a method of the handler object? The `sayHi` function and its `this` argument are passed as parameters.

Comment: You probably should not use a proxy here. Just return a simple wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is what [the specification says](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-call-thisargument-argumentslist) should happen when a proxy is used:

> ### 10.5.12 [[Call]] ( `thisArgument`, `argumentsList` )
>
> The [[Call]] internal method of a Proxy exotic object `O` takes arguments `thisArgument` (an ECMAScript language value) and `argumentsList` (a List of ECMAScript language values) and returns either a normal completion containing an ECMAScript language value or an abrupt completion. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Let `handler` be `O`.[[ProxyHandler]].
> 2. If `handler` is **null**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 3. Assert: Type(`handler`) is Object.
> 4. Let `target` be `O`.[[ProxyTarget]].
> 5. Let `trap` be ? GetMethod(`handler`, "**apply**").
> 6. If `trap` is **undefined**, then 
>    a. Return ? Call(`target`, `thisArgument`, `argumentsList`).
> 7. Let `argArray` be CreateArrayFromList(`argumentsList`).
> 8. Return ? Call(`trap`, `handler`, « `target`, `thisArgument`, `argArray` »).

Or in short, the relevant things here are:

1. Take the proxy handler object, call it `handler`.
2. Take the `apply` method from `handler`, call it `trap`.
3. Use `Call(handler, trap, args)`. Where `args` is essentially, the list of arguments needed to use `Call` with the original function.

[The `Call` from step 8. in the specifications](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-call) is executing a function, where the **first** argument is the function to execute, the **second** is the value for `this`.

Since the ECMAScript specification says that the second value should be `handler` and at step 1. `handler` is set to the [[ProxyHandler]] then the behaviour observed falls in line with the specified behaviour.